# how to use pandas to read some Excel file at a time?

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = pd.read_excel(U"D:/data/data/000852.SZ.xls")
data2 = pd.read_excel(U"D:/data/data/000526.SZ.xls")
print(data1)
print(data2)
```

How do I use the Panda function to do a single read on multiple Excel files, instead of repeating the same code and reading each file step by step?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. What do you mean by "at a time"? You can [edit] to clarify.

Comment: emm,I mean, how do I use the Panda function to do a single read on multiple Excel files, instead of repeating the same code and reading each file step by step:)

Comment: Does this answer your question, the same applies for `read_csv` as `read_excel`? [Import multiple csv files into pandas and concatenate into one DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906474/import-multiple-csv-files-into-pandas-and-concatenate-into-one-dataframe)

Comment: ok,i know what to do,ty